# How can I have 2 different fragment, implementing same methods without writing the code twice?

Tags: android, oop, kotlin, data-binding, interface

I have a fragment screen where there is a form that is used to create Questions and Answers for my app. For this fragment, I use data binding, then I created many functions to validate the form, and check other stuffs.

Now, I'm creating a different fragment screen, where I'll be able to edit this Questions and Answers that were created, and for this, I want to use the same functions that were used when I created on the other fragment, for example to validate the fields that the user is editing.

**I thought about implementing an Interface, and put these common functions there, so I could use it on both fragments. However, in these functions I use DataBinding, and I don't know how I can use it on the interface, so it would get the correct XML variables regarding to one fragment, or the other one.**

On the screenshot bellow, it shows that I'm trying to use the binding, however I can't specify which one I'm using, otherwise the code will work only for a fragment, and not for both. Consequently, I tried to declare as DataBindingUtil but it didn't work.

[Screenshot interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LOaGb.png)

Comment: Parent class that they both extend. Common functions go in the parent. Or a single Fragment class with if statements based on which version it represents.

Comment: What do you mean by using DataBinding in these functions? Please post some code with examples, so we can give better answers.

Comment: @TorkelVelure I access the xml fields using databinding. I've edited the post with a screenshot.

Comment: @Tenfour04 so you mean create a parent class for both fragments, instead of using a interface? To be honest I still don't get why the real difference between a parent class and an interface

Comment: Yes. A parent class would have access to all the functions and properties of a Fragment. If your common functions need access to any Fragment or Context functions, an interface won't work unless you declare these properties and functions in the interface. The advantage of an interface is that it doesn't have to participate in class hierarchy. Inheritance adds complexity, so interfaces are preferable if you don't need the super-class features.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with this approach you could add the views as fields in the interface:

```
interface IQuestionForm {
   var newQuestionTextInput: EditText
   var answer1TextField: EditText

  fun validateAllParametersToCreateNewQuestion(){
    var allTextInputSet = true
    if (newQuestionTextInput.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
      newQuestionTextInput.error = "You have to enter the question"
      allTextInputSet = false
    }
    if (answer1TextField.text.isNullOrEmpty()){
      answer1TextField.error = "You have to enter an answer"
      allTextInputSet = false
    }
    ....
  }
}
```

Then initialise those fields after creating the binding in the fragment.

Comment: Gotcha... I'll do that instead of trying to pass the binding to the interface. Thanks a lot